# extract data from output in bat file

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file

I want to add my ip to system/user environment in a bat file.

This is the code of the bat file

```
curl http://httpbin.org/ip
```

This is the output:

```
{
   "origin": "1.2.3.4"
}
```

I want to set environment `set ip=1.2.3.4`

How should I do that?

Comment: Seeing as you tagged your question Windows7, I think you should really consider using Powershell instead of batch. It is a more modern and powerful shell native to Windows.

Comment: Do you think ps, can make it eaiser to accomplish this task?

Comment: I really haven't used Powershell that much, but from what I've seen it's going from the 80's code madness that is batch to some modern code API trying to put at ease both bash and .NET users. If you've worked 20 years in batch I suppose there's no use learning PS now, but any less than that should quickly have a huge increase in productivity

Comment: @Aaron I've only been learning batch for a short time, but I know what is easy to achieve. It's a much smaller language, so easier to learn and know its limitations and trickery.

Comment: @Aaron I can answer questions like this in a few minutes. To learn the powershell equivalent would take me a lot longer.

Comment: I suppose it really depends on a lot on your experience with different kind of languages. I'll post an equivalent Powershell answer in a few minutes, you'll be the judge of what you would have found the most easily

Comment: @Aaron Note also that Windows 7 comes with PowerShell 2.0. PowerShell is now on version 5.0 so there are version differences to take care off. Cmd is pretty much fixed in functionality since Window XP.

Comment: If they're handling their language well, their versions are retro-compatible and each version should be documented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### I want to add my IP address to the system/user environment in a bat file.

```
curl http://httpbin.org/ip
```

This is the output:

```
{
   "origin": "1.2.3.4"
}
```

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
rem @echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=2" %%i in (`curl http://httpbin.org/ip`) do (
  setx ip %%~i
  goto :done
  )
:done
endlocal
```

Notes:

- `skip=1` is used to skip the first line `{`.
- `goto :done` is use to skip the last line `}`.
- `~` is used to remove the quotes from the IP address.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.
- [setx](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) - Set environment variables permanently, SETX can be used to set Environment Variables for the machine (HKLM) or currently logged on user (HKCU).

Comment: Why enableDelayedExpansion?

Comment: @Amina Required for most batch thingies. Doesn't have anything specifically to do with this.

Comment: I was testing my batch file with `set` instead of `setx` and I had `echo !ip!` after `set`, which requires `enableDelayedExpansion`. If it works without you can remove it.

Comment: Thanks. I removed it, and change it to `set ip=`

Comment: I also don't have `curl` installed so I was testing with a text file containing the `curl` output.

Comment: `set ip=` is temporary ... and will remain set only for the duration of the current `cmd` shell. Your question said "system/user environment" which I understood to mean you wanted it permanently set.

Answer (score 2):

This would be the equivalent in PowerShell :

```
$ip = curl http://httpbin.org/ip | Select-String -Pattern "[0-9.]+" | Select Matches
Set ip $ip.Matches.Get(0).Value
```